# Self not defined in AlienInvasion Program?

Tags: python, function, class

I thought that importing pygame and the sys module would suffice but it does not. I'm aware that self is not defined in my code. I'm using the a book for this project and the instructions are as follows:

```
import pygame
import sys

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage assets and behavior"""

def __init__(self):
    """Initiaze the game, and create the game resources."""

pygame.init()
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
```

**when i run my code, I get a self not defined error. find below my code:**

```
import pygame
import sys

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage assets and behavior"""

def __init__(self):
    """Initiaze the game, and create the game resources."""

pygame.init()
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
```

this is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: you need to indent `def __init__(self)` to be inside class AlienInvasion. spacing in python matters. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7024476/3462319)

Comment: You need to copy the indentation from the book, not just the text.  If that's actually how the code appears indented in the book, then *throw the book away* - it's useless.

Comment: One of the first things you should have learned about Python is that indentation is part of the syntax. It takes the place of `{}` for marking code blocks in languages like C, JavaScript, and PHP.

Comment: This code never uses the class or function that it defines.

Answer (score 1):

you made a mistake in class structure

```
import pygame
import sys

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage assets and behavior"""
   def __init__(self):
       """Initiaze the game, and create the game resources."""
       self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
```

Test:

```
AlienInvasion()
```